# was going to, tomorrow

Tags: future-in-past

Assuming that I told you 2 days ago, "I promise I will call you tomorrow".
But I didn't. So now I have to apologize you.
Then I say "I promised I would call you the next day." is it correct?

Comment: To make the time-frame comprehended by the follow-up sentence more coherent, you could preface it with "Two days ago," as in "Two days ago, I promised I would call you the next day." but the syntax of the wording you suggest is error-free.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's correct. *Would* is the preterite form of the modal auxiliary *will*. Referring to a past event, you're putting both *promise* and *will* in the preterite. And the implicit reference for *tomorrow* is *now*: it means the next day in relation to *now*. Since you're putting the whole thing into the past, it makes absolute sense to do what you've done and to transform *tomorrow* into something which doesn't have that implicit reference.

Comment: And "the next day" is generally used to refer to a tomorrow that was mentioned in the past so it's correct in popular usage as well as in a grammatical sense

Comment: I agree with Lachlan.